# How do you get DIRECTION of PDF is L2R or R2L

Tags: pdf

I want want to programmatically read a PDF file to find out if it is read either L2R or R2L.

How can I determine this programmatically?

I use ASP.NET C#.

Comment: I've edited your question to read clearer as a question, but can you edit your question to elaborate on what programming language you're using, what do you intend to do with the script, have you attempted this already?

Comment: *it is read either L2R or R2L.* - what exactly do you mean? Do you mean whether the drawn text is containing text usually read L2R/R2L? Or do you mean the order the text drawing operations in the PDF content streams appear in?

Comment: How do you get PDF is a DirectionR2L or DirectionR2L
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#DirectionR2L

Answer (score 0):

我找到讀取方法了,若有更好的方法請再回覆,方法如下:

I find reading method, and if a better way please reply again, as follows:

---

//讀取左翻或右翻

//reading DIRECTION is a L2R or R2L

```
booFlipLeft = true;


if (objReader.Catalog != null) {

    if (((PdfDictionary)objReader.Catalog).Contains(PdfName.VIEWERPREFERENCES) == true) {

        if (((PdfDictionary)((PdfDictionary)objReader.Catalog).Get(PdfName.VIEWERPREFERENCES)).Contains(PdfName.DIRECTION) == true) {

            if (((PdfName)((PdfDictionary)((PdfDictionary)objReader.Catalog).Get(PdfName.VIEWERPREFERENCES)).Get(PdfName.DIRECTION)).Equals(PdfName.R2L) == true) {
                booFlipLeft = false;

            }

        }

    }

}

TextBox1.Text += "翻頁:" + (booFlipLeft == true ? "左翻" : "右翻") ;

TextBox1.Text += "Flip:" + (booFlipLeft == true ? "Left" : "Right");
```